# Installation KnpSnappyBundle Error

Tags: symfony

In using KnpSnappyBundle i get an error (white page) and that's the steps:
i make this line in composer.json `"knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master"`and i use this commande to install this bundle `composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle "dev-master"`besides i add these lines in config.yml:

```
knp_snappy:
pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"" 
    options:    []
image:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe\""  
    options:    []
```

and i create a method in my controller:

```
public function pdfhtmlAction()

    {    

          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(); 

             $html = $this->renderView('PdfHtmlBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'user'  => $user
));

return new Response(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
    )
);

    }
```

in my twig i put:

```
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-muted" style="width: 50%;">Email</td>
          <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-muted" style="width: 50%;">{% trans %}PhoneNumber{% endtrans %}</td>
          <td>{{ user.phoneNumber }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

in my routing i put :

```
pdf_spfhtml:
    pattern:  /pdfhtml
    defaults: { _controller: "PdfHtmlBundle:Default:pdfhtml" }
```

and when i make my method in controller like that  it work successfully :

```
public function pdfhtmlAction()

    {    

          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(); 
         return $this->render('PdfHtmlBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
              'user' => $user

        ));

    }
```

That does mean the error is in my method controller when i try to render html to pdf, can someone help me to fix it and i'm debutant in symfony2.

Comment: Did you install [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) ??

Comment: i have installed a .exe

Comment: You work under msWindow ? So your config is not correct : /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf ???

Comment: I change the config by changing the path of the knp_snappy and i make the path like this can you verify because the same error a white page knp_snappy and sorry  if i disturb you.

Comment: Have you checked Symfony's log file for errors?

Comment: when i follow the execution a message appears:  failed to load data response